# Send Office365 e-mail using AzureAD authenticated user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .Net Core MVC Web application that authenticates the user using AzureAD. At some stage I need to send an e-mail on behalf of that user.
I searched for some options and apparently I can do that using Microsoft Exchange Service or Office365 but for both options I need to get the user's credential.

An example using Office365 is below however I do not know how to user the signed in info to pass to the SMTP server.

My (partial) HomeController:

```
private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _principal;
public HomeController(IPrincipal principal){                
            _principal = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;                
        }
```

I can use `_principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value` to get the user's e-mail address but how do I get the password?

Am I in the right path or am I missing anything?

```
public static void SendEmail(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string subject, string content)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com"; 
        client.EnableSsl = true;            

        MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();
        newMail.To.Add(toAddress);

        newMail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        newMail.Subject = subject;
        newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        newMail.Body = "<html><body>" + content + "</body></html>";                        

        client.Send(newMail);
    }
```

I'm sorry if this is a broad question but I really need some light on how to achieve this. I'm happy to provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> At some stage I need to send an e-mail on behalf of that user.

Per my understanding, you could use the [cloud-based email service](https://sendgrid.com/solutions) SendGrid to handle email delivery on behalf of your authenticated user's email address. The code for sending the email to `test02@example.com` for the user `test01@example.com` would look like this:

```html
var client = new SendGridClient("<SendGrid-ApiKey>");
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    From = new EmailAddress("test01@example.com", "test01"),
    Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
    PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
    HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
};
msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test02@example.com", "Test02"));
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Detailed tutorial, you could follow [sendgrid-csharp](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp).